# ViewDoesNotExist in webfaction

Tags: python, django, webfaction

I upload my project using FTP on webfaction and now using putty i logged in. But same project is working fine but after uploading it is giving error viewdoesnotexist i dont know what changes i have to do i am a newbie. And yeah! a have made changes in apache httpd.conf and created scene_finder.wsgi.

ViewDoesNotExist at /index
Could not import scene_finder.views. Error was: No module named views
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://gbtech.webfactional.com/index
Django Version: 1.3
Exception Type: ViewDoesNotExist
Exception Value:
Could not import scene_finder.views. Error was: No module named view

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure PYTHONPATH holds the directory of your site? Just to make sure, you can always add this to the wsgi script: import sys  if '/my/path/' not in sys.path: sys.path.append('/my/path') .

Comment: In which file i should have append and how?

Comment: @ Damian Ok i added in urls.py

import sys
sys.path.append(r"/home/webapps/django/scene_finder/scene") 
scene is the folder name where view.py exist..


Nw where i have done wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `scene_finder.wsgi` there'll probably be some code that sets up your PYTHONPATH. Make sure it includes `/home/webapps/django/scene_finder/scene`.